# invalid URI - How to prevent, URI::InvalidURIError errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I got the following back from delayed_job:

```
[Worker(XXXXXX pid:3720)] Class#XXXXXXX failed with URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): https://s3.amazonaws.com/cline-local-dev/2/attachments/542/original/mac-os-x[1].jpeg?AWSAccessKeyId=xxxxxxxx&Expires=1295403309&Signature=xxxxxxx%3D - 3 failed attempts
```

The way this URI comes from in my app is.

In my user_mailer I do:

```
  @comment.attachments.each do |a|
    attachments[a.attachment_file_name] = open(a.authenticated_url()) {|f| f.read }
  end
```

Then in my attachments model:

```
  def authenticated_url(style = nil, expires_in = 90.minutes)
    AWS::S3::S3Object.url_for(attachment.path(style || attachment.default_style), attachment.bucket_name, :expires_in => expires_in, :use_ssl => attachment.s3_protocol == 'https')
  end
```

That being said, is there some type of URI.encode or parsing I can do to prevent a valid URI (as I checked the URL works in my browser) for erroring and killing delayed_job in rails 3?

Thank you!

Comment: I tried ' open( URI.parse(URI.encode(     a.authenticated_url()  )) ' but that errord with OpenURI::HTTPError: 403 Forbidden

Comment: That error doesn't mean the URL is bad, it means the page isn't available to you.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has (at least) two modules for dealing with URIs.

[URI](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/uri/1.9.2/frames) is part of the standard library.

[Addressable::URI](http://rubydoc.info/gems/addressable/2.2.2/frames), is a separate gem, and more comprehensive, and claims to conform to the spec.

Parse a URL with either one, modify any parameters using the gem's methods, then convert it using `to_s` before passing it on, and you should be good to go.

> I tried ' open( URI.parse(URI.encode( a.authenticated_url() )) ' but that errord with OpenURI::HTTPError: 403 Forbidden

If you navigated to that page via a browser and it succeeded, then later failed going to it directly via code, it's likely there is a cookie or session state that is missing. You might need to use something like [Mechanize](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mechanize/1.0.0/frames), which will maintain that state while allowing you to navigate through a site.

---

EDIT:

```
require 'addressable/uri'

url = 'http://www.example.com'

uri = Addressable::URI.parse(url)
uri.query_values = {
  :foo => :bar,
  :q   => '"one two"'
}

uri.to_s # => "http://www.example.com?foo=bar&q=%22one%20two%22"
```

Comment: Thanks Tin Man.. When you 'modify any parameters' can you explain. better yet provide an example for the URL above? thxs

Comment: I added a simple example of how to use Addressable. Beyond that I think you need to go through the documents, decide how it fits your use-case, and learn the gem. It's very good. Ruby's URI has some growing pains right now related to encoding of parameters so any manipulation of that part of a URL I pass to Addressable.