# ruby what makes a valid URI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting invalid URI issues, so what exactly makes a valid URI?

Comment: what is the URI you are using?

Comment: And what's telling you it is invalid?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730698/invalid-uri-how-to-prevent-uriinvalidurierror-errors

Comment: Your first question was much better and had an appropriate level of detail. Please don't ask questions twice, instead see [How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the highest level a URI reference (hereinafter simply "URI") in string form has the syntax

```
[scheme:]scheme-specific-part[#fragment]
```

If you are interested to know the complete set of rules, read [RFC-2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396)

I doubt whether you need to know all the syntaxes. I have never read the entire RFC and still I am using URI in development and day to day use. So, you better post the URI you are having problem with. Then, people here can point out the specific problem.